# could not get a field value by reflection hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have problem when update object in jpa

i have bean user

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_program_rating")
    private List<Rating> ratingList = new ArrayList<Rating>();
}
```

and

```
public class Rating extends BaseModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_program_rating", nullable = false)
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_prog_rate")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Program program;
}
```

when try to update that give me exception :  could not get a field value by reflection 
that happen when table rating have rows

> ERROR TransactionInterceptor:434 - Application exception overridden by commit exception
>       com.vodafone.visradio.dataaccess.exception.DataAccessException:    org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.vodafone.visradio.dataaccess.model.Rating.id

any help about this problem
 thanks

Comment: How did you try to access it by reflection?

Comment: @m3th0dman : i dont access any thing by reflection

Comment: Well does your Rating class have a getter method for your `id` attribute?

Comment: Don't you have by some change another id in the BaseModel?

Comment: @Matthias : getter and setter Exists

Comment: @m3th0dman : base model not have id

Comment: And the getter returns a `Long` or a `long`. I am not sure that hibernate & reflection is working too well with autoboxing, but it is just a wild guess.

Comment: @Matthias all getter return Long

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the mapping annotations. Remove the `@JoinColumn` annotation from `ratingList` and add `mappedBy` attribute:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user") 
private List<Rating> ratingList = new ArrayList<Rating>();
```

where `user` is the property name in the `Rating` entity that has a `@ManyToOne` association with `User`.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can cause this is if you don't quite do your criteria correctly.

For example if you put `"rating"` in the criteria, but you actually need `"rating.id"`. That will cause this same error message to come up.

So if you've checked your Entity definitions check to make sure you don't have a simply mistake like this in the actual query that is failing. That was the issue when I was getting a similar error.